# What is the meaning of 'more approximate'?

Tags: meaning

The book Principles of Programming Analysis contains a weird sentence that I do not fully understand:

> Returning to the discussion of safe approximation note that if we modify Table 1.1 to include the pair (z,2) in RDentry(5) and RDexit(5) we still have safe information about reaching definitions but the information is **more approximate**.

I am confused about the more approximate part. Does this mean it is a more, or less precise approximation than before? I can read it both ways and both make sense to me.

Comment: Why would you think 'more approximate' could mean 'more precise'?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey The definition of Merriam Webster said 'Almost exact or correct'. So more almost correct would mean more precise?

Comment: Consider approximate to mean 'not exact' in this context.

Comment: Approximate = rough.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey That makes sense to me and answers the question. I found a relevant question that I could not find earlier where someone ran into the same problem except with the word 'very'. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37053/what-does-very-approximate-mean